# Using git/git-svn, how can I get out from remotes/trunk

Tags: git, git-svn

My directory structure was like this:

```
feipu123/
feipu123/trunk
feipu123/trunk/work
feipu123/tags
feipu123/branch
```

I used this command:

```
git reset --hard remotes/trunk
```

My directory structure became:

```
feipu123/
feipu123/work
```

What can I do to make the file folders become the former look?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you reset your master branch to match the tip of a remote branch. If you want to return the master branch to it's previous state, you can use `git reflog` to find what commit you were on right before the `git reset --hard remotes/trunk`. The output of `git reflog` should contain something similar to this

```
f9e224f HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to remotes/trunk
37abebb HEAD@{1}: xxxxx
```

Use the hash that is one step before the reset in the reflog to do

```
git reset --hard 37abebb
```